# Automatically partition a table in mysql (pymysql) everyday for new data

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Im still figuring out partitioning in SQL.

Is it possible to automatically partition a table everyday for new data? For example, on Monday, I have one partition. On Tuesday, automatically create a new partition, insert that day's data into the new partition and so on... Is reorganize partition the right way to go?

Comment: Think about creating daily event which creates partitions for some future period. I.e. get current partitioning info and current date, build SQL statement which adds partitions, for example, until 7 next days (in general it will create only one partition, but if previous event was skipped by some reason it may create more than one partition), and dynamically execute it.

Comment: hopefully you are doing this so its easy to purge off? If you are after performance gains you probably won't gain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `REORGANIZE` of a "future" partition is the right way.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint for a discussion of why, plus sample Perl code.

Do not create more partitions that you need immediately; it leads to inefficiencies.  Instead, check to see if you need a new partition more often than simply "just in time".